# Make a list with Name and number, swift xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

In the ThirdArray under //Seattle I want make a list of names and numbers. What should I do?

and how would I highlight the phone number so when the user touches it, it calls the number?

thank you, This is my first language

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController{


    var FirstTableArray = [String]()

    var SecondArray = [SecondTable]()

    var ThirdArray = [ThirdView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        FirstTableArray = ["Washington", "California", "Alaska","About Us"]

SecondArray =
                [SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["Seatle","Spokane","Tacoma"]),
                    SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["Los Angeles","San Diego","Sanjose"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: ["Anchorage"]),
            SecondTable(SecondTitle: [">"])]

            ThirdArray =
                [ThirdView(ThirdViewArray:
                        //Seattle
                        ["Joe: 222-222-2222",

                        //Spokane
                        "Lars- 333-333-3333",

                        //Tacoma
                        "Oien- 444-444-4444"]),
```

Comment: Maybe it could help to know that you can present your text in a UITextView. You can configure the text view such that it recognise phone numbers. Then you'll get them highlighted and clickable for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first suggest getting your data in a dictionary, you can declare it like this :

```
var ThirdDictionary: <String, Int> = ["Joe": 2222222222, "Lars": 3333333333, "Oien": 4444444444]
```

Then it would be possible for you to populate a UITextField for example by getting the data out of the dictionary into a UITextView like this :

```
for (name, number) in ThirdDictionary {
    myTextView.text = "\(number)"
}
```

Lastly UITextView has a dataDetectorTypes property that you can set in order to make this a clickable phone number :

```
myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.PhoneNumber
```